# Can't type at Linux login prompt

Tags: linux, intel, yocto, buildroot, arduino

I've just opened up two brand new Intel Galileo Gen 2s and am looking to login to their default Linux distro via terminal (ie. no SD card used). I am coming across a weird, identical issue with both which leads me to believe I am missing a step/doing something wrong. Please could someone help?

### Steps I've tried

The exact steps I have taken since unboxing the Galileos are:

1. Powered on the Intel Galileo Gen 2 and connected a UART cable, ethernet cable and micro usb to USB cable to a Mac. I also connected a keyboard directly to the Galileo's USB port.
2. Installed the 1.1.0 firmware via Intel's firmware updater software for Mac
3. In a Linux VM running inside the Mac, show the terminal input from the Galileo via `sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0`
4. Restarted the Galileo.

At this point, with my keyboard plugged directly into the Galileo, I was able to navigate through the boot options (ie. `Press Enter to directly boot` and selecting what to boot from). After selecting the default boot option, the Galileo booted and arrived at:

```
Poky 9.0.4 (Yocto Project 1.4.4 Reference Distro) 1.4.4 clanton /dev/ttyS1
clanton login:
```

At this login prompt, the cursor is flashing as you'd expect, however as soon as I try typing a single character, the cursor kind of freezes by just constantly being visible instead of flashing. I also do not see the character showing at the login prompt as you'd expect as you type something. I am unable to do anything else until I restart, at which point the same thing happens again.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Cbj53nf8) are the log files from when attempting to boot with this approach.

### Other attempts

I'm unsure if my peripheral setup is wrong, the way I am accessing the terminal, if I need to install some more drivers to support I/O or something else.

I have also tried using a [custom Linux image](https://github.com/andy-shev/buildroot/tree/intel/board/intel/galileo) via an SD card but have got the same end result (log files from that attempt [here](https://justpaste.it/1kz1t)).

Curiously, I have been able to follow [these](https://lisha.ufsc.br/teaching/esl/exercises/acessingbash.html) instructions to telnet into the Galileo and interact with it via a keyboard (keyboard plugged into the computer, not the Galileo this time), however I want to be able to avoid the Arduino IDE as required in these instructions as I believe I need to do that when booting from a Linux SD card which is what I ultimately want to do.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If TTY1 is stuck, perhaps try CTRL+ALT+F2 to switch to TTY2 and try from there.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment @Stewart! Sorry shout that command go to the terminal window on my Mac's Linux VM or directly to the Galileo? I have tried both and it doesn't seem to do anything but guessing I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!! Turns out I was using a faulty FTDI cable!